# How can I adjust Flutter such that Fleksy recognizes colors and changes accordingly?

Tags: flutter, dart, colors, keyboard

I'm making an app and I can't figure out what I need to change in order to make Fleksy recognize colors and change accordingly.

Fleksy is a keyboard app on devices that has a chameleon theme which changes according to the apps' color.
For instance, my app's main colors are white and red. Thus, in order to match general theme, I want Fleksy to change it's color to red whenever keyboard appears on the screen.

Is there something that I have to do within Flutter or there's a specific way to make this work?